# How to determine if a view can actually be seen by the user, and is not being obscured by other views

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, overlap

I have a typical Button view with the attribute of `View.VISIBLE` that could be overlaid by a fragment or soft keyboard.  It is **NOT** contained in any scrollviews. Is there any way to determine if it is actually viewable by the user and is not being obscured or partially overlaid in any way?

I'm not talking about `.getVisibility()`, I know it is set to `View.VISIBLE`.

Can the canvas be interrogated, etc. or further existing attributes to look at?